# How do I make SVG level from center of polygon rather than bottom?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I have a rather simple svg icon for a dropdown button. I want to level it with the text from the dropdown button, so that the center of the text levels with the center of the svg polygon.

As of now, it levels with the bottom of the polygon.

The svg:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='#FFFFF'>
    <polygon
            opacity="0.5"
            points='0,0 100,0 50,50'
    />
</svg>
```

It is implemented as such(React styling) for a button element:

```
background: `url(${require("./assets/icons/select_downarrow.svg")}) no-repeat`,
backgroundSize: "10px",
backgroundPosition: "calc(100% - 15px) center",
```

It will "level" with the very buttom of the SVG arrow. I wish for it to level with the center of the polygon, is that possible to do from the SVG element itself, or will this have to be done by the styling?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way, is to set the `line-height` of your text to be the same height as your image.  This works great as long as your text doesn't need to wrap.

```css
button {
  background-color: #eeeeff;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffee;
}

span {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button>

  <svg width="100" height="100" fill="#FFFFF">
    <polygon opacity="0.5" points="0,0 100,0 50,50" />
  </svg>
  
  <span>Some text here</span>

</button>
```

Comment: I think I phrased myself poorly, what your example shows is exactly what I have now and do not want. I want "some text here" to start at 50% of the height of the polygon, so it levels completely with each others center - if that makes sense?

Comment: Then just set `line-height: 50px;`

Comment: On the span? Or the svg?

Comment: On the `<span>`.